# How to remove automatic scrolling in a winform application?

Tags: winforms, datagridview, autoscroll

I have a winform ( Windows Form) application, in .NET 4.0. On the main screen, I have two DataGridView, one on the top of the second. If I start my application on a small screen (say 1024x768), I don't completely see the second DataGridView. When I click inside this second DataGridView, the screen automatically scroll to show me the complete DataGridView. I DONT want that behaviour cause now I cannot see important information in my first DataGridView!.
Then how could I remove this annoying behaviour?

FYI: my application is optimized for 1280x960 screen.

thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be looking for [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.autoscroll%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Setting this property to `false` should resolve the issue.